# Do sugar alcohols have the potential to get a person drunk?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, biochemistry, alcohols

From what I understand is ingesting high amounts of sugar alcohols can lead to various effects such as abdominal pain and diarrhea, my question is, is there a certain amount of sugar alcohol if ingested cause drunkenness (even if it causes a person to be in a critical state or death) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "sugar alcohol"?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! It's high time you and @matt_black take a look at [the almighty Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_alcohol#Production_and_structure). :P Oh, and a cross-site duplicate: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/can-sugar-alcohols-and-glycerol-in-particular-cause-intoxication

Comment: @matt_black Here is a list of sugar alcohols: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_alcohol#Common_sugar_alcohols

Answer (score 1):

Sugar alcohols are only partially absorbed. It is very unlikely anyone will become intoxicated with sugar alcohols. Also, their effects are less likely to cause intoxications.